# How do I extra different series of variables from a pca data frame and plot them separately?

Tags: python, dataframe, scatter-plot, pca

I have a data frame that went through PCA with 4 different series of data (plate 1 to 4) in python, and was plotted as a single scatter plot. How can I modifiy the codes to separate the data and make 4 different scatter plots (i.e. one for plate 1, another for plate 2 etc)? Here are my codes to generate the first graph? Thanks!

```
pca_all = pd.DataFrame(
data    = PCA(n_components = 2)
            .fit_transform(
                data.reshape((n_plates * n_rows * n_columns), n_points)
            ),
columns = ["component 1", "component 2"],
index   = plates.columns)

_, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 10))
sns.scatterplot(
x       = "component 1",
y       = "component 2",
hue     = "plate",
data    = pca_all.reset_index(level = 0),
palette = sns.color_palette(n_colors = 4),
ax      = ax);
```

Comment: your code isn't running. But you can check out the following notebook: https://www.kaggle.com/mehmetkasap/plotly-3d-scatter-multiple-subplots

Comment: Also check out the documentation: https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.subplots.make_subplots.html